# Do I need a page for both "Web Design [city-name]" and "Website Design [city-name]", or can I rank for both by using "Website Design [city-name]"?

Tags: seo, search-engine, search-engine-bots

If Google's keyword planner shows me the keyword "Web Design [city-name]" gets ~880 searches, and "Website Design [city-name]" gets searched ~620 times, can I get ranked for both keywords by using "Website Design [city-name]"? Or would I need a page specifically for "Web Design [city-name]" and "Website Design [city-name]"?

Answer (score 0):

You need one for both of those. They are individual things and totally different keywords

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can rank for both by using “Website Design [city-name]”.